# compiler error "could not load embedded UI class EmbeddedUI.EmbeddedUI from assembly"

Tags: user-interface, .net-4.0, wix

I'm trying to create an application using WIX 3.7 UI. If I assembly where my code is using. When compiling for .NET 4.0 I get the following error message:

> SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v2.0.50727
>   Error: could not load embedded UI class EmbeddedUI.EmbeddedUI from assembly: CustomActions

I have tried different things in CustomAction.config. The current version is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

The class is implemented as follows:

```
public class HelloWorld : IEmbeddedUI
{
    #region IEmbeddedUI Members

    public bool Initialize(Session session, string resourcePath, ref InstallUIOptions internalUILevel)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test256");
        return true;
    }

    public MessageResult ProcessMessage(InstallMessage messageType, Record messageRecord, MessageButtons buttons, MessageIcon icon, MessageDefaultButton defaultButton)
    {
        return MessageResult.OK;
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In the file Product.wxs:

```
<UI Id="Embedded">
     <EmbeddedUI Id="MyTest" Name="CustomAction45CA.dll" SourceFile="..\CustomAction45\bin\Debug\CustomAction45CA.dll">
     </EmbeddedUI>
</UI>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
When I switch from Framework in AssemblyProperties from 4.0 to 3.5 then everything works.
And the test with bootstrapper application works with framework 4.0.
I suspect that the MakeSfxCA.exe makes my dll broken. But I do not know what I can do. I have already experimented with MakeSfxCA.exe.config and x86 and x64.

I would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Error will be thrown only with EmbedddedUI. CustomAction from the same dll runs with message in installer log SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319

Comment: Configuration file for embedded UI is EmbeddedUI.config and not CustomConfig.config. Renaming of CustomConfig.config to EmbeddedUI.config solved the problem